# c# generics with abstract method

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to implement some generic method for an abstract class as follows :

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass : MyBaseObject {
    public MyAbstractClass() : base() { } // there is a parameterless constructor...
}

public class MyList<T> where T : MyBaseObject, new() {
    // a generic container that is designed for the base class
}

//--- some paint control of mine
public class PaintControl : IDisposable {
    public void InitDrawItems(MyList<MyAbstractClass> items) {
        // paint items => this is where the compilation error occurs...
    } 
}
```

I get the following compilation error :

> Error 24  'MyAbstractClass' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MyList'

Of course, I'd like to use the abstract MyAbstractClass class (which has several children to handle painting accordingly).
Is there a way around this?

**EDIT:** I did make the class Abstract to make absolutely sure the children actually DO implement the abstract methods.

Comment: You cant new up an abstract class

Comment: From the official documentation: _The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. **To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract**_.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint

Comment: Ok so 2 ways out 1. Make MyAbstractClass non-abstract OR use the a specific non-abstract child in  the `PainControl`, correct?

Comment: Can you post an example for that? I've got a lot to learn about interfaces!

Comment: @neggenbe maybe, maybe not. Why did you make `MyAbstractClass` abstract in the first place and what does `InitDrawItems` do? Do you want that method to be generic? It's possible, using type constraints

Comment: @neggenbe interfaces won't solve the problem, you can't create interface instances either.

Comment: Why do you need the `new()` constraint at all there? What are you trying to do with it? Are you writing `new T()` anywhere? If so, why?

Comment: You could also remove the `new()` constraint of `T`. That literally means that you cannot use abstract classes or interfaces with `MyList`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yep found that out - interfaces is NOT the way to go. As for your question - I have a paint control that paints different forms. Abstract base class is a "DrawItem" to be drawn and each child overrides the "Draw" method. And yes, at some point, I use the `new T()` contraint, that's the whole point !

Comment: @neggenbe But you said that `MyList<T>` is "*a generic container that is designed for the base class*". Given that, what will `new T()` instantiate? It can't instantiate the base class, since that by definition can't be instantiated. What are you *trying* to do here?

Comment: @canton7 the base class is abstract as well... What IS working is to make `MyAbstractClass` non-abstract and implement all abstract methods of `MyBaseObject`. To force implementation, I mark all methods as virtual an simply throw a `NotImplementedException`... This works, but I'd rather have the abstract security layer at compilation-time...

Comment: @neggenbe Please answer my question. You're simultaneously saying "I want to be able to create new instances of my base object" and "I don't want to be able to create new instances of my base object". Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

[new()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) doesn't allow abstract classes and interfaces to be used as `T`, because they are not instantiable. `new()` means the generic type must declare a public parameterless constructor eligible for instantiation of an object.
So you have one option, in my opinion:
remove the `new()` clause, if you are ok with any abstract type derived from `MyBaseObject` being used with your generic. As your class is indeed abstract and a child of `MyBaseObject`, that would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is problem is caused by [generic type variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). Declaring a concrete type actually creates a new type at compile time. The *type* parameters in a class can't be converted implicitly between types. There's no inheritance relation between `MyList<MyBaseObject>` and `MyList<MyConcreteObject>`.

Conversions are only permitted for generic interfaces or delegates.

There are two ways to fix this - use an interface instead of a concrete class, eg :

```
class MyList<T>:IList<T> where T : MyBaseObject, new() 
{

}

class PaintControl  {
    public void InitDrawItems<T>(IList<MyAbstractClass> items) //where T:MyAbstractClass,new()
    {
        //var anItem=new T();
    } 
}
```

Or make `InitDrawItems` itself generic:

```
public void InitDrawItems<T>(MyList<T> items) where T:MyAbstractClass,new()
{
    // No compilation errors here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `new()` constraint for `T` type in `MyList`, since it's specifying that you can only use types that can be initialize - abstract ones can't.

You can check more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Answer (score 0):

As @Martin pointed out in the comments, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint):

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. **To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.**

And the code you have written to define `MyList<T>`:

```
public class MyList<T> where T : MyBaseObject, new()
```

says `MyList<T>` is a generic class where T must have the new constraint (be type that you can instantiate).

So the reason of your compilation error on the code:

```
public void InitDrawItems(MyList<MyAbstractClass> items)
```

is because `T` in this case is `MyAbstractClass` which is an abstract class which cannot be instantiated.

So you options are as follows:

1. Make the method generic, like so:

   ```
   public void InitDrawItems<T>(MyList<T> items) where T : MyAbstractClass, new()
   {
       // paint items => this is where the compilation error occurs...
   }
   ```
2. Remove the new constraint from `T` in `MyList`
3. Make `MyAbstractClass` a normal class and not abstract.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems a bit of a workaround, but it actually makes lots of sense...

I know for sure which item of the list I am working with (I am looping through items). Since this item has been created, it is FOR SURE a non-abstract class. And hence, I can call the activator for that item, instead of `new T()` :

```
public void InitDrawItems(MyList<MyAbstractClass> items)
  foreach (var item in items) {
    Type type = o.GetType();
    // type is definitely NOT abstract, since the object was created, so it is a
    // non-abstract child class and I create the right "copy" of the item !
    MyAbstractClass newItem = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as MyAbstractClass;
    // ... do whatever I need with the item
  }
}
```

NOTE: as for generics, it makes sens that calling `new T()` isn't allowed for abstract classes. Put it that way : a container of generic abstract items contains items of a derived child class since the abstract parent class cannot be instantiated. So calling `new T()` would definitely lead to an issue if allowed by the compiler : which child class should it be?!?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you can't instantiate an abstract class and so `T = MyAbstractClass`  clashes with the `where T : new()` constraint.